Dimming light with no switch
I just moved to a new place and noticed that one of the lights is Super dim when I turn it on. When I tried to take it down to replace it i noticed that it had a dimmer box attached. The light switch only has on/off no extra switch for the dimmer. Any suggestions to fix this?

Can you upload pictures of the "dimmer box"?

so the switch goes true dimmer

Could the dimmer box be a remote controlled one (not necessarily a smart or WiFi remote control but something older)?
